# Bash: Reading variables containing single or double words from a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to read contents of a file into variables using bash v4.1.x The input file may look like this:

```
1373232436 785907701 "abc 245" 0 1
1373232436 1048824909 "def pqr" 1 0
1373232486 785907701 "uvw ghn" 0 1
1373232486 1048824909 "1109 xyz" 1 0
```

If I use

```
cat <filename>|while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
do
...
...
done
```

I should get col3 values to be

```
"abc 245"
"def pqr"
"uvw ghn"
"1109 xyz"
```

Comment: Do you need all the variables or just this one? If so, you can use another field separator: `IFS='"'` and get the 3rd field.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear. I need the values of all variables, that's why I can't use IFS.

Comment: Then you get to re-assemble manually or actually parse the lines.

Comment: Is there always exactly one space between the double quotes, or is that just the example you've given?

Comment: Is it only the third column that can be quoted, and is it always quoted? Using a regular expression to split the line into columns may be a better idea than letting `read` perform word-splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that only the third field can be quoted as shown, I would use a regular expression to split each line into columns.

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^(.*)\ (.*)\ (\".*\")\ (.*)\ (.*)$ ]] || continue
    col1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    col2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    col3=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    col4=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    col5=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`gawk`+`FPAT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content)

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^ ]*)|\"([^\"]*)\""} {print "\nLine: " NR; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'  test.csv
Line: 1
1373232436
785907701
"abc 245"
0
1

Line: 2
1373232436
1048824909
"def pqr"
1
0

Line: 3
1373232486
785907701
"uvw ghn"
0
1

Line: 4
1373232486
1048824909
"1109 xyz"
1
0
```

Note1: FPAT is gawk feature. May not be available with your awk version.
Note2: Just realized, that incidentally, example in the link I mentioned above deals with requirement very similar to yours, though I had written that regex myself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, your input file is essentially a csv file, with field separator=space.
Then you can use `csvtool`:

```
csvtool -t " " cols 1-6 test.csv | while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6; do
    ...
    ...
done
```

run `csvtool --help` for more details.

Note: There will NOT be surrounding double quotes around `col3` data. So you would get `abc 245` & not `"abc 245"` in the value.

Comment: Sorry, csvtool is not available on either cygwin or CentOS linux. However, I get the idea. I may be able to change the input file into CSV format and then use available unix utilities to parse the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use:

```
grep -Eo '"[^"]*"|\w+' file
```

to read each quoted column separately from your input file.

You can use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

numcols=$(awk -F '"[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]]+' '{print NF-1; exit}' file)

n=1
while read -r w; do
    echo "$w"
    (( (n++ % numcols) )) || echo "<-- End of line $(( (n / numcols) )) -->"
done < <(grep -Eo '"[^"]*"|\w+' file)
```

For your input file it gives:

```
1373232436
785907701
"abc 245"
0
1
<-- End of line 1 -->
1373232436
1048824909
"def pqr"
1
0
<-- End of line 2 -->
1373232486
785907701
"uvw ghn"
0
1
<-- End of line 3 -->
1373232486
1048824909
"1109 xyz"
1
0
<-- End of line 4 -->
```

You can process them individually instead of doing `echo "$w"`.